# Redirect users in adonis js without permission

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I have this in my view

```
@if(auth.user.id == post.user_id)
            <div class="all-edit">
                <div class="post-body">
                    <a href="/posts/edit/{{ post.id }}">(Edit)</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            @endif
```

When user that made the post click it, then it takes them to the edit post page. But users that did not create post visit the url it shows the edit post page. i want them to be redirected to the home page instead,

Answer (score 0):

### Answer on [forum.adonisjs.com](https://forum.adonisjs.com/t/redirect-users-that-is-not-the-owner-of-posts/6724/3)

You can create custom [middleware](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/middleware).

Logic :

1. Get post id with
   [`params`](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/routing#_route_parameters)
   object
2. Get user from [`auth`](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/authentication)
   object
3. Custom logic (if post owner)

   3.1. if false : redirect  (with
   [`response.redirect()`](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/response#_redirects))

   3.2. if true : call [`await next()`](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/middleware#_upstream_downstream_middleware)

---

Get post :

```js
const post = await Post.find(params.id)
```